# jquery regex expressions alert box

Tags: javascript, regex

i have this code which validates fields using regex expressions. at this moment it makes a popup in case something is wrong. i'd like to let go of this and to show a message maybe next to the field or above it. any help please?

here is the code:

```
<script>
function validate(form) {

var pwd = form.elements.pasa.value;
var eml = form.elements.pasa2.value;



if(5 > pwd.length || pwd.length > 25){
    alert("error");
    return false;
}

var rgx = /[a-zA-Z]|\d+/;
if(!rgx.test(pwd)){
    alert("error");
    return false;
}


rgx = /\s/;
if(rgx.test(pwd)){
    alert("error");
    return false;
}

if(8 > eml.length || eml.length > 40){
    alert("error");
    return false;
}

var rgx = /^\s*[a-z\d_]+(\.[a-z\d_]+)*@[a-z\d\-]{1,255}\.[a-z]{2,6}\s*$/;
if(!rgx.test(eml)){
    alert("error");
    return false;
}

rgx = /\s/;
if(rgx.test(eml)){
    alert("error");
    return false;
}


return true;
}

</script>
```

and the form:

```
<form name="Form1" method="post" action="action1.php" language="javascript" onSubmit="return      validate(this);" id="Form1">
<input name="pasa" class="field" type="text">
<input name="pasa2" class="field" type="text">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

thanks

Comment: I wouldn't reinvent the wheel (although I did), [this plugin](http://elclanrs.github.com/jq-idealforms/) might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `alert()` calls with code that puts a message in the right place. Things like `createElement`, `appendChild` and other fundamental DOM methods might be useful.